# How to alter Java strings contain only certain alphabetical characters

Tags: java

how can I alter text string fields in java to only contain certain alphabetical characters (f,-)

in this format: 2f5-4, 2f6, 8f9
Only numbers f numbers and
numbers f number - numbers

Comment: can you provide an example of an input string, and the output string you want to produce.  Can you also clarify that you want to amend the content of the string, rather than 'validate' it.

Comment: In a textfield i want it to accept only this type of values:

Comment: 2f6
2f9
6f10

5f9-2
3f4-9

numbers f Numbers

and

numbers f numbers - numbers

Comment: I want only two characters that is "f" and "-" only and all  other numbers

in the same sequence

Comment: I believe you have accepted the incomplete answer, which does not satisfy the sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a regular expression to check, if the `String` in your text field is valid:

```
\d+f\d+(?:-\d+)?
```

Java code sample

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d+f\\d+(?:-\\d+)?");
for (String s : new String[] {
    "2f6", "2f9", "6f10", "5f9-2", "3f4-9"
}) {
    System.out.println("String: \""+s+"\" match: "+pattern.matcher(s).matches());
}
```

Comment: Hi..what does colon (:) signify here?

Comment: @AmberBeriwal `(?:something)` is a non-capturing group with content `something`. The matcher doesn't need to extract this part of the string as a group, therefore I "tell it" not to collect this data. If you left out the `?:` part, you could access this substring from the matcher created using  `Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);` after you found a string by using `matcher.group(1)`.

Comment: Thank You. I didn't knew this. But above regex is also clearing `5f5-`.

Comment: @AmberBeriwal: `5f5-` is not matched by the regex, which is AFAIK what the OP wants (*"Only numbers f numbers or numbers f numbers - numbers"*)

Comment: I verified it using [regex101](https://regex101.com/) and [regecr](http://regexr.com/)

Comment: @AmberBeriwal Only the `5f5` part of the string is matched, see https://regex101.com/r/sX6dK0/1 . `matches` however requires the whole string to match. To do the same on `regex101.com`, you need to use the regex `\A\d+f\d+(?:-\d+)?\z`.

Comment: ok...got it. thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

Regex expression =>

```
  (([0-9]+)([f])([0-9]*)|(([-])([0-9]*)))\w+
```

Comment: It does not work for the input given in comments.